usage of registerCompletionItemProvider to replace internal text
I am trying to figure out how to use the Monaco editor Monarch editor configuration language.
In particular, I would like to do replacements of variables within the completion item.
I am trying to make this syntax work:
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('cobol', {
    provideCompletionItems: function() {
        var suggestions = [
            {
                label: 'EXEC CICS FREEMAIN',
                kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Snippet,
                insertText: [
                    'EXEC CICS FREEMAIN',
                    '    SET(${1:pointer})',
                    'END-EXEC.'
                ].join('\n'),
                insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet,
                documentation: 'Release memory in the CICS region with a placeholder for pointer.'
            }
        ];
        return { suggestions: suggestions };
    }
});

I resorted to using chatgpt to generate that because I can not find proper documentation  for registerCompletionItemProvider.
That syntax is supposed to allow the user to press tab and step through the placeholders.
It does not work; it just inserts the replacement text.
Here are my question:
How can I get the placeholders to allow me to step through and insert the variables?
